# Can ReadWriteOnce PVC be rejected by AWS EBS/GCP PersistentDisk upon Pod Rescheduling?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

Assume currently I have 2 `PVC`s with `ReadWriteOnce`, claimed by `Pod #1` and `Pod #2` respectively. Both are running on `Node #1`.

Next, `Pod #2` is updated with the newer Docker image. However, at the same time `Pod #3` is run and allocated to `Node #1`. Since `Node #1` is now full, `Pod #2` could only be allocated by Kubernetes to `Node #2`.

Since AWS EBS and Google PersistentDisk could only be mounted on single Node, would `Pod #2` become unable to connect to the-previously-claimed `PVC`?

If yes, how to avoid having this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is the downside of pv/pvc with the current storage deliveries of AWS and GCE.

To avoid this, you would have to use a different storage infrastructure which does not have this limitation. Possibilities are CEPH, Gluster, scaleIO (and others). These solutions abstract the storage away from the disks and provide a storage layer which is not node dependent anymore.

Comment: It's unfortunate for PD and EBS, as this kind of use case should be very common. I would prefer using managed storage rather than maintaining myself. Is there any other solution if I still want to use PD and EBS safely? Use dynamic PV maybe?

Comment: So far nothing is on the horizon at the AWS and Google. DigitalOcean seems to be doing something which might help. And you are certainly not alone in wanting a ready to go solution (I want the same, and I think many others want this too)

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be a problem. When `Pod #2` is scheduled to `Node #2`, Kubernetes should automatically detach the volume from `Node #1` and attach it to `Node #2` for `Pod #2` to use there.

Comment: I think it shouldn't happen. The volume is still needed by `Pod #1` in `Node #1`. Thus, K8S shouldn't detach it from `Node #1`. Unless K8S also reallocate `Pod #1` to `Node #2`...

Comment: Since you have 2 PVCs, I assumed you had 2 corresponding PVs. You're right that if you only have 1 PV you will run into problems with Pods scheduled on different nodes.

Comment: If we need to have one to one mapping between PV and PVC, it defeats the purpose of having PVC, doesn't it? In that case, the behavior would be the same as having dynamic PVC (which is not terminated when the Pods get deleted)